# Phonegap lowlatencyaudio plugin music is too noisy in Android only

Tags: cordova

I am developing app for iOS and Android platform using Phonegap build. I wanted to multiple music files [.wav] and can be played at a time.
Hence, I took LatencyAudio plugin [from here](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/).

Here is my code from jquery file:

```
 var click_sound = "sounds/sound1a.wav";
 var music_mp3 = "sounds/gameover.wav";

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady () {
                                preloadFX: function ( id, assetPath, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success,fail,"PGLowLatencyAudio", "preloadFX", [id, assetPath]);
                                },

                                preloadAudio: function ( id, assetPath, voices, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PGLowLatencyAudio", "preloadAudio", [id, assetPath, voices]);
                                },

                                play: function (id, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PGLowLatencyAudio", "play", [id]);
                                },

                                stop: function (id, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PGLowLatencyAudio", "stop", [id]);
                                },

                                loop: function (id, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PGLowLatencyAudio", "loop", [id]);
                                },

                                unload: function (id, success, fail) {
                                    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PGLowLatencyAudio", "unload", [id]);
                                }
  });

    PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadAudio( music_mp3 , music_mp3, 1, function(msg){ //Success}, function(msg){ //Error Call back});
    PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadAudio( click_sound , click_sound , 1, function(msg){ //Success}, function(msg){ //Error Call back});   

     PGLowLatencyAudio.play(music_mp3);
     PGLowLatencyAudio.play(click_sound );
```

This works perfectly in iOS and in Android, only in Android `music_mp3` file is too noisy and loud sound.I am not understanding what needs to be fixed? Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we need to replace callback `preloadFX`  with `preloadAudio`. Since, by default, there is one instance that will be stopped & restarted when you hit play.
Hence, update the lines as :

```
    PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( music_mp3 , music_mp3, 1, function(msg){ //Success}, function(msg){ //Error Call back});
    PGLowLatencyAudio.preloadFX( click_sound , click_sound , 1, function(msg){ //Success}, function(msg){ //Error Call back});
```

Please go through the complete documentation.